# VB6 DLL Isolation Error

Tags: vb.net, dll, vb6

I have a VB6 DLL, and i need to use it in VB.Net project , so that, in order to use this DLL in  both projects without interfering each other, i have to make it's property "ISOLATED  = TRUE" ,  but when I set this property to TRUE , the following ERROR appeared

> Problem isolating COM reference 'HMS_Server': Registry key 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{821ee06b-d656-4c63-ad24-0f4e5b916a8b}\InProcServer32' is missing value '(Default)'.  HMS_WF3

any suggested solution for this issue?

during Googleing here and there i found the follwing

[error description 1](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/174466/error-isolating-com-reference-at-non-creatable-classes)

[error description 2](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.interop/2006-01/msg00097.html)

but still . what I can do?? changing  instancing  from PublicNotCrearable could help me??

if yes.. to what can i change  PublicNotCrearable  ???

Comment: Is there more to the error message as there was here? http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/174466/error-isolating-com-reference-at-non-creatable-classes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I convert VB DLL into .Net DLL and it's working fine now with me ...